# Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib' : file not found

Tags: pyodbc, unixodbc

I am working in python. I am using Macbook for development and OS version is Catalina. I am trying to connect MSSQL Server with pyodbc. I installed SQL Drivers and its dependencies as well. But while connecting I am getting this error.

```
Exception -  ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I Checked the file path `'/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib'`. Actually file is available there.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, one reason DLLs don't load is not because they don't exist but because the *dependencies* they need do not exist. No idea how to track dependencies on Mac, you'll need to find that out elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue?

Comment: @MihailKuznetsov I installed version 17. It's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**
For 13 version need open ssl v 1.0.0 , you can try it.

> brew install
>   https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb

Comment: The above won't work: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/47348
My recommendation is to use the v17 driver and if you MUST use v13 then to install openssl v1: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/47348#issuecomment-560001981